# Using transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateY(2px) css Property how to rotate the dropdown arrow?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

```js
gradeexpanded:false,

gradeOnClick: function (event) {
      this.gradeexpanded = !this.gradeexpanded;
    },
```

```css
.dropdown-check-list {
  margin-left: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  width: 300px;
  color: #262626;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #ffff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 40px 10px 10px;
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20%;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
}
.dropdown-check-list ul.items {
  background-color: #ffff;
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: none;
}
.dropdown-check-list ul.items li {
  background-color: #ffff;
  list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-check-list.visible .anchor {
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F0F0F0;
  background-color: #ffff;
}
.dropdown-check-list.visible .items {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 325px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ffff;
  display: block;
}

.gradeexpanded{
  transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateY(2px);
}
```

```html
 <div
            class="dropdown-check-list"
            :class="{ visible: gradeexpanded }"
            tabindex="100"
          >
            <span class="anchor" @click="gradeOnClick"
              >Gtest</span
            >
            <ul class="items">
              <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="HR 2062 : 2011"
                  class="vh-product" value="H2011"
                  v-model="checkedNames"
                />
                <label class="productlist-specific" for="HR 2062 : 2011"
                  >H2011</label
                >
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter2">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="E250A"
                  class="vh-product"
                  v-model="checkedNames" value="E250A"
                />
                <label class="productlist-specific" for="E250A">E250A</label>
              </div>
           </ul>
           </div>
```

[image]

Using transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateY(2px); css Property how to rotate the dropdown arrow.

I have written below code for dropdown code in html and css, As shown in the picture below i am unable to rotate the arrow icon accordingly.

Issue is at present, weather the dropdown is open or not, it is maintaining in the same state.

Comment: The `@click` event listener is apart of Vue, if your using `vue.js` make sure to add that tag!

Comment: Seems like you would add it here ```.dropdown-check-list .anchor:hover:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(2px);
}```

Comment: BTW you have it set to -135 so using 180 when clicked won’t make it flip 180deg from that position. The degrees will be from its original rotation of 0deg. If your intent is to get the arrow to point up then you’ll want 45deg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following css:

```css
.dropdown-check-list.visible > span.anchor:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown-check-list");

dropdown.addEventListener("click", function () {
  this.classList.toggle("visible");
});
```

```css
.dropdown-check-list {
  margin-left: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  width: 300px;
  color: #262626;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #ffff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 40px 10px 10px;
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20%;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
}
.dropdown-check-list ul.items {
  background-color: #ffff;
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: none;
}
.dropdown-check-list ul.items li {
  background-color: #ffff;
  list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-check-list.visible .anchor {
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
  background-color: #ffff;
}
.dropdown-check-list.visible .items {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 325px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ffff;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-check-list.visible > span.anchor:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
  <span class="anchor">Gtest</span>
  <ul class="items">
    <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter">
      <input type="checkbox" id="HR 2062 : 2011" class="vh-product" value="H2011" />
      <label class="productlist-specific" for="HR 2062 : 2011">H2011</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="E250A" class="vh-product" value="E250A" />
      <label class="productlist-specific" for="E250A">E250A</label>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown arrow is a pseudo-element which is an inline element and Transform property can't be applied to inline elements. Just make your dropdown arrow `display: block` and it should work as expected.

```
.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
 ...
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are toggling the class `gradeexpanded` on parent div right? So the css class should be `.gradeexpanded .achor:after` right?

```
.gradeexpanded .anchor:after {
   transform: rotate( 180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate( 180deg);
   transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

code:

```
.dropdown-check-list.gradeexpanded .anchor:after{
    transform: rotate( 45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate( 45deg);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```